# Yii Datatprovider remove rows

Tags: php, yii

I am in the position where I need to remove records form a dataprovider. Long story shot, I have encrypted data in my db that is decrypted using the `afterfind` method. I need to ensure the decrypted string is 20 characters long and show the result in a cgrid view.

I have tried the `visible option`, but this hides the data on a per column basis. I have tried the `rowCssClassExpression` which successfully hides the rows on the screen using `display:none`, however, it still shows 1 of 1200 results even though only 10 match and also page 1 has one result, page 2 no results, page 3 2 results etc.

Currently I am able to get this working by doing a `cdbcommand` `queryAll` and then looping through and calling the object like so:

```
foreach($data as $key=>$d)
{
     $lengthCheck = Data::model()->findByPk($d['id'])->checkLength;
     if($lengthCheck !== true)
     {
         unset($data[$key]);
     }
```

etc.

I can then use the resulting array in an `arrayDataProvider`, so effectively I can get the information I need using this methods, however, It is taking over 2 seconds per record, so effectively this would be over 3 minutes for 100 records.

Does anyone have an idea of how I could do this in a smarter/faster way?

Comment: You making query for each row, so 100 of your records will generate 101 query to db. It's very bad idea. Get data to array using `CDbCommand queryAll()`, and then perform your decryption in for each loop with length check. This will do some speed up but generally it's bad idea.

Comment: Is `Data` the same model class containing the encrypted data?

Comment: @topherkanyuga yes it is ie `self`